# how to make navigation menu background color transparent?

Tags: css, background-color

code: style.css

```
.nav-links .navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #b8e5fa;
  border: none;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

In this code I have navigation menu and I am giving background color as I mention in my css. Now, I want to make my background color transparent with the same color code. How can I do this ? please help me.

Thank You!

Comment: google about rgb colors, you will get your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `rgba()` to specify colors, with opacity.

```
background-color : rgba(184, 229, 250, 0.5);
```

Here I have used the RGB of `#b8e5fa` and an opacity of `0.5`.

Here is an example:

```css
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color : rgba(184, 229, 250, 0.5) !important;
     border: none !important;
 }

body {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/07/07/12/31/lime-2481346_960_720.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Inverted Navbar</h3>
  <p>An inverted navbar is black instead of gray.</p>
</div>

</body>
```

**[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwQoPY)**

Read more about `rgba` here : [CSS Colors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp)

Comment: Please mark it as the right answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> `#b8e5fa` is equivalent `rgb(184,299,250)` and `hsl(199°, 87%, 85%)`, So for color with opacity you can use `rgba` or `hsla` :

```
.nav-links .navbar-inverse {
     background-color: rgba(184, 229, 250,0.2);
     //more code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code Since you're using bootstrap and you already used it's navigation class ".navbar-inverse" which comes up with default black color. So if you want to overwrite it simply use

```
.nav-links .navbar-inverse {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

for making it transparent
if you want to make it of any other color you can override it(bootstrap's css) too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rgba or used like that

```
 background-color: transparent;
```

**OR**

```
background-color: rgba(184, 229, 250,0.2);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do so by using 
**background-color:transparent;**

```
.nav-links .navbar-inverse {
 background-color:transparent;
 border: none;
 height: 100px;}
```